# What is advantage of using ROOM rather than saving as Static value?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm thinking about using `Room` library for the new android application I am developing.

I used to make a class for `Static value` and saved data gotten from a server in that class.

for example,

#### StaticValue.kt

```
class StaticValue {
    companion object {
        lateinit var users: ArrayList<User>
    }
}
```

#### Get data and save

```
var tmpArr = ArrayList<User>()
for (i in 0 until jsonObjArr.length()) {
   tmpArr.add(User(jsonObjArr[i] as JSONObject))
}
StaticValue.users = tmpArr
```

I think Google officially recommends using `Room` for the MVVM design pattern, but I am not sure about using `Room` just for saving and query data.

Is there any advantage to use `Room` and query data from local DB, rather than saving data as `Static` and use it from `Activity` or `Fragment`?

Thanks for all your help and advice.

#### Edit

Sorry for the lack of info on the question.

The problem is that the app requires log-in, and all data gathered from the server must be deleted when log-in session expires.

Is it better not to store and update data every time in the DB that only needs to be alive before the app shuts down or logs out, or just save as StaticValue? I wonder what the efficiency aspect is.

Comment: @a_local_nobody good call, not even mentioning ROOM exposes data as LiveData that can be observed as changes happen.

Comment: @a_local_nobody data must be updated every login. If session expires, data should be updated from server with login again. Is it better not to store and update data every time in the DB that only needs to be alive before the app shuts down or logs out, or just save as StaticValue? I wonder what the efficiency aspect is.

Comment: @a_local_nobody right.. sorry for lack of info. Should've checked there is enough description. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: in terms of efficiency it probably doesn't matter enough to worry about it, databases are used when data has to be stored and used again in future, so if you have no need for a db then you shouldn't be using it. if your app works using static variables - which probably don't even have to be static, then use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Room is permanent database for saving data in user local storage but static data only lives as log as application is running , the usage of Room and static object is completely different and in some point you need to use both of them